# How to inject WCF Service Implementation into another WCF Service with Autofac

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, autofac

I have multiple WCF Services hosted in IIS and configured with Autofac.

**Global.asax**

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceB>();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceC>();

var container = builder.Build();
AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;
```

**web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  ...
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    <serviceActivations>
      <add service="ServiceA, MyServicesAssembly" relativeAddress="./ServiceA.svc" factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf" />
      <add service="ServiceB, MyServicesAssembly" relativeAddress="./ServiceB.svc" factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf" />
      <add service="ServiceC, MyServicesAssembly" relativeAddress="./ServiceC.svc" factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf" />
    </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
<system.serviceModel>
```

**Service Implementations**

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA 
{
    public ServiceA()
    {            
    }
}

public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    public ServiceB()
    {            
    }
}

public class ServiceC : IServiceC
{
    public ServiceC(IServiceA serviceA)
    {            
    }
}
```

As you can see, ServiceC is different from the others and need an implementation of IServiceA.
Autofac can't resolve it, because there is no registration for IServiceA.

So I change the registration to this:

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>().As<IServiceA>();
```

Autofac can now resolve ServiceC successfully, but the WCF hosting is not working anymore:

> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

**So my question is:**

Is there a way that I can have both, a hosted WCF Service instance, and the possibility to pass a Service Implementation to another Service? All configured with AutoFac?
I'm also thinking of a workaround, but everything that comes to my mind results in a huge effort.
I know that these services needs to be refactored, so that there is no need to pass in another "service". But this is a different story.

Comment: If you follow some best practices of SOA/microservices, then you want to separate out the service layer from the business logic, the latter having nothing to do with WCF at all (another .dll) leaving the WCF layer to be a thin wrapper via a `facade pattern`.  With this in mind, instead of injecting a WCF instance of `ServiceA` into `ServiceC` you inject say `ServiceCBusiness` (which inherits perhaps `IServiceAImpl`).  Then whenever `ServiceC` invokes `IServiceA` it **won't go over the WCF-layer** (and possibly **network layer**) thus **improving performance**.

Comment: ....but then again, I never like the idea of injecting a business layer because they are generally `static`.  You can read up more on SOA patterns here  https://patterns.arcitura.com/soa-patterns/design_patterns/service_facade

Comment: @MickyD Yes, injecting a service or business logic of another service is both wrong in terms of real microservices. The services here are all running in the same process and nothing is really decoupled. There is much more to do... but for now I am only looking for a quick solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you want to expose a component as a set of services as well as
>   using the default service, use the `AsSelf` method:

```
//...

builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>()
    .AsSelf() //<--
    .As<IServiceA>();

//...
```

This will associate the class and interface together so that `IServiceA` can be injected as needed and it will be resolved to `ServiceA`. This also allow the WCF to not break as `ServiceA` is registered.

Reference [Autofac Documentation: Registration Concepts](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#services-vs-components)